# How to remove backspace between the frames in video_trimmer package

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, flutter-video-player

I would like to remove the black space between each frame video. I using the package called video_trimmer: https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer

[trimmer video example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t33g0.png)

This is my Trim Editor so far:

```
TrimEditor(
    trimmer: controller.trimmer!,
    viewerHeight: 50,
    viewerWidth: Get.width,
    maxVideoLength: const Duration(seconds: 30),
    onChangeStart: (value) {
     controller.startValue.value = value;
    },
    onChangeEnd: (value) {
      controller.endValue.value = value;
    },
    onChangePlaybackState: (value) {
     controller.isPlaying.value = value;
    },
  ),
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
TrimEditor(

    trimmer: controller.trimmer!,
    fit: BoxFit.fill, // Add this line <===
    viewerHeight: 50,
    viewerWidth: Get.width,
    maxVideoLength: const Duration(seconds: 30),
    onChangeStart: (value) {
     controller.startValue.value = value;
    },
    onChangeEnd: (value) {
      controller.endValue.value = value;
    },
    onChangePlaybackState: (value) {
     controller.isPlaying.value = value;
    },
  ),
```